# Do I need a special kind of locksmith for accurate installation of latches in a solid door?

Tags: doors, lock, latches

I have some expensive doors made of solid oak and I need them to be drilled and mortised for latch sets. I am a little nervous about hiring a random locksmith to do this work, because if they screw up, it could ruin a *very* expensive door. Are there special kinds of locksmiths that work on high-end furniture and such that I should be looking for? What are they called?

Comment: They are called carpenters.

Comment: @SolarMike I already talked to high end carpenter. He said that I need a top quality locksmith, without further specifying what that meant.

Comment: I have installed dozens of lock sets I have templates and the proper sized hole saws for quite a few doors, to tell the truth I would be more comfortable with a carpenter they hang doors quite often , I can’t say I have ever seen a locksmith ever do anything but pick a lock and replace hardware, but I don’t use locksmiths on site,  by the time you pay the service call fee you can buy a new lock and I can take about any lock out in a minute or 2 with a battery drill. I agree with solar mike, find a general contractor if your carpenter is not up to the job.

Comment: I would third the vote for a carpenter/GC doing the job. Heck, you could do it yourself - they make jigs (available at any big box store) that clamp on the door to align the (included) hole-saws to ensure your holes are properly aligned and square to the door. If your carpenter doesn't have one, then he's definitely _not_ the right guy for the job!

Comment: They make jigs for exactly this sort of thing. I think I paid $25 from bargain outlet for a kit that had the  jig and 2 hole saws (one for knob, one for the lock). If the lock (on edge of door) and hinges need to be recessed so they sit flush, you'd need to route or chisel those. For that I would hire someone if you're not experience with, because one slip could mess up your door.

Comment: Sorry, but talking about a cheapy jig is irrelevant here. This is about a mortised lockset, which either requires skill or a tool that usually costs >$1000. Find your local specialty door retailer and ask who they use to install mortise locks. (As with most things, *some* carpenters can do this, and *some* locksmiths can do this.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate not necessarily. The OP says "drilled and mortised". For a "standard" lockset, you drill holes, then you mortise for the latch plate (& the door frame for the strike plate). It _could_ be a mortised lockset which does require a full mortise to slide the entire lock into. OP isn't explicit enough (at this point) for us to know the difference. Considering you're the only one who read it as "mortised lockeset" and 4 of us read it as a standard lockset, it's obviously not clear and we don't yet know who is right.

Comment: @FreeMan -- I sit corrected. Perhaps the OP can weigh in on exactly what kind of a lockset is involved.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - No implication whatsoever that you're the one in the wrong, we just don't know yet. I'll sit next to you. ;)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  Specialist tools? I fitted a mortice lock on my solid oak front door with a flat bit and a chisel.

Comment: You need a *joiner*, not a carpenter.

Comment: @SiHa -- I did say "skill or a tool..." Still waiting for details from the OP, though. (Hint. Hint.)